# Azure Mobile App controller and Visual Studio Setup

Tags: visual-studio, controller, azure-mobile-services

I am creating various controllers for my Azure mobile app. All the controllers will be using the same Azure SQL resource and blob storage , where can i define all the parameters so that i am repeating identical declarations all the time?

Answer (score 0):

> All the controllers will be using the same Azure SQL resource and blob storage , where can i define all the parameters so that i am repeating identical declarations all the time?

Per my understanding, you could define a base class for your controllers and define your resources under the base class, then each controller 
inherits the base class, then you could reuse the pre-defined resources under the base class. The following is the sample code, you could refer to it:

**Base TableController:**

```
public class TableControllerBase<TData>: TableController<TData> where TData : class, ITableData
{
    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TData>(context, Request);

        //initialize your resources (e.g. BlobClient)
        // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient BlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }
}
```

For your TableController, you need to inherit the base class as follows:

```
public class TodoItemController : TableControllerBase<ToDoItem>
{
   //CURD
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend you follow adrian hall's book [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/) about developing Azure Mobile Apps.

Comment: So this class, which file would they by placed in? Would it be a separate C# file?

Comment: I would prefer to create a new c# file under the `Controllers` folder.

Comment: You could also update your question with the code snippet from the related controllers, then we could better understand your question and provide the solution. Any concerns, feel free to let me know.

Comment: The controller is not yet completed, but i will be having many controller using the same SQL database, so my aim was to just define it only once in my mobile app.